# Mysql package could not be located Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation, mysql, php

I'm trying to install mysql and php on my laptop, but when I run :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-php5 mysql
```

I get

```
E: The mysql-server-php5 package could not be located
E: The mysql package could not be located
```

I tried to change the server for Ubuntu Software update but it made no difference.

Comment: 16.04 has PHP7: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php-mysql

Answer (score 3):

Your package name is wrong (mysql-server-php5 doesn't exist).  Try this instead:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-cli
```

If you are trying to do local website development, you may also want to install Apache, so you'd use this instead:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-cli apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
```

**An additional advisory to install packages in linux:** You don't need to write complete package name atonce if you are not sure. You should write first few characters which you know/remember like: `sudo apt-get install mys` then pres `TAB` key two times, after this a list of packages starting from `mys` will appear. It's very helpful in browsing related packages too. (**Note:** before doing this you may want to update your local package list by command: `sudo apt-get update`)

Comment: not work, I forget say that Im using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please edit your question and add the command you ran in your latest test, as well as the output you got.

Comment: this is the ouput: 
`Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package php5-cli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  php7.0-cli`

Comment: I solve by runnig the following command `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5.6-cli apache2 libapache2-mod-php5.6
` greatings.